# Designing a REST API path for importing products from an csv file

Tags: rest

In my application, I upload a *csv file having all the products* using [HTML file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp). An internal worker process gets a notification via a trigger from the file directory as soon as the file upload is completed. At that point the internal worker process calls a REST API (with the name of the file only) to start processing the csv file to insert into the database.

I don't know whether my call to process the csv file is restful. I came up with the following paths by considering **products** as the resource. Is this design restful? If this is not restful, shouldn't I use behavior as a REST but use WCF or such RPC calls.

```
http://localhost/products/import/productsfile.csv *(GET method)*
http://localhost/products/productsfile.csv/import *(GET method)*
http://localhost/products/ *(POST method with the name of the file)*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Largely an opinion but recently I have been inspired the some google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods) on the topic

A POST to a collection is typically expected to create a single entity in the collection.  POSTing to `/products` for example should create one product entity.

I would use a POST to `/products:upload` with json body that contains a key of file_uri and value of the uri that the file can be reached at.